# C# measurement conversion with StreamReader only reading only 1 line from file

Tags: c#, split, streamreader

Okay so I'm working on a project for the conversion of measurements using StreamReader to read a file with the following list of conversions:

```
ounce,gram,28.0
pound,ounce,16.0
pound,Kilogram,0.454
pint,litre,0.568
inch, centimetre,2.5
mile,inch,63360.0
```

When the program runs it will ask the the user to input the amount they want to convert followed by the measurement the want to convert, followed by the measurement they want to convert it into. So e.g. 5,ounce,gram

After getting the input the program would look at the file and calculate the conversion rate so 5 ounces = 140 grams so the program would display as a end result

"5 ounce equals 140 gram"

The problem I'm getting with this program is the fact that the StreamReader is only reading the first line of the convert.txt file, for example if I was to put 2,pound,ounce it would return back the text for the first line followed by a message "Not Matched" so the it would look something like this:

Please input the amount, to and from type (Ex.5,ounces,grams): 
2,pound,ounce
ounce,gram,28.0
Not Matched

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
namespace Soft140AssPt3V2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line, programStart, programEnd, j, l, lineTotal = "";//linetotal to take all lines from the file
        double factor, endResult, amount;
        string[] SplitData = new string[2];
        string[] fileLines;
        StreamReader unitsOfMeasurement = new StreamReader("../../convert.txt"); //Reads the convert.txt file
        Console.WriteLine("convert.txt has uploaded");
        while ((line = unitsOfMeasurement.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lineTotal += line + "\n";
        }
        fileLines = lineTotal.Split('\n');//place file lines in an array of string

        //Get inputs
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input the amount, to and from type (Ex. 5,ounces,grams):");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fileLines[i]);
            SplitData = fileLines[i].Split(',');
            programStart = SplitData[0];
            programEnd = SplitData[1];
            factor = Convert.ToDouble(SplitData[2]);

            string[] filter = userInput.Split(',', ' ', '/', '.');
            amount = Convert.ToDouble(filter[0]);
            j = filter[1];
            l = filter[2];
            if (j == programStart)
            {
                endResult = (factor * amount);
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0} {1} equals {2} {3}", amount, filter[1], endResult, filter[2]);
                Console.ReadLine();


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Matched");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        unitsOfMeasurement.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You declare "no match" **before** the for() loop has iterated all lines.  It needs to go *after* the for() loop.  You got into this trouble primarily by writing a big blob of code, not thinking about how you are going to split the functionality of the program into classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
StringBuilder lineTotal = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = unitsOfMeasurement.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lineTotal.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
}

fileLines =  lineTotal.ToString().Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine},
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
StringBuilder lineTotal = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("../../convert.txt"))
{
lineTotal.Append(line);
}
fileLines =  lineTotal.ToString().Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine},
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Solution 3:**

```
string fileName = "../../convert.txt";
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(line => 
                                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why combine and then split? `File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)).ToArray();` does everything.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thank you , thats very good point, i have added as a solution, but i feel `File.ReadLines()` is much better than `File.ReadAllLines()`.

Comment: Yes, I agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the optimized Code (You can further modify it as per your requirement):

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                double factor, endResult, amount;
                string[] fileLines;

```
            StreamReader unitsOfMeasurement = new StreamReader("../../convert.txt"); //Reads the convert.txt file
            Console.WriteLine("convert.txt has uploaded");

            fileLines = unitsOfMeasurement.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n');//place file lines in an array of string

            //Get inputs
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input the amount, to and from type (Ex. 5,ounce,gram):");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            bool blnFound = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] filter = userInput.Split(',');

                if ((filter.Length == 3) && (filter[1].Trim() == fileLines[i].Split(',')[0].Trim()))
                {
                    blnFound = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(fileLines[i]);
                    factor = Convert.ToDouble(fileLines[i].Split(',')[2]);
                    amount = Convert.ToDouble(filter[0]);
                    endResult = (factor * amount);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n{0} {1} equals {2} {3}", amount, filter[1], endResult, filter[2]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (blnFound == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Matched");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            unitsOfMeasurement.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```